# Factorization of $(q^q - (-1)^{(q-1)/2})/(q-(-1)^{(q-1)/2})$

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

Prove that for any prime $q > 3$,  $(q^q - (-1)^{(q-1)/2})/(q-(-1)^{(q-1)/2})$ is never prime (or disprove by counterexample). If this is true, is there a possible trivial factorization for $(q^q - (-1)^{(q-1)/2})/(q-(-1)^{(q-1)/2})$?

The first few examples appear to be

$q=5$ and $(5^5-1)/4=11*71$, $q=7$ and $(7^7+1)/8=113*911$, $q=11$ and $(11^{11}+1)/12=23*89*199*58367$, $q=13$ and $(13^{13}-1)/(13-1)=53*264031*1803647$.

Let $p*p_2$ be the non-trivial factorization of $(q^q - (-1)^{(q-1)/2})/(q-(-1)^{(q-1)/2})$. Then, for all odd primes $q$,

$q=3$, $p=1$, $p_2=7$

$q=5$, $p=11$, $p_2=71$

$q=7$, $p=113$, $p_2=911$

$q=11$, $p=58367$, $p_2=407353$

$q=13$, $p=1803647$, $p_2=13993643$

$p$ and $p_2$ seem to be of relative same size, and with $p_2$ being approximately $7.76p$.

Can anyone find the interesting pattern here?

Comment: With factordb and PARI/GP, I found no counterexample. But examples with large smallest prime factors exist, so there seems to be no reason to prevent the existence of such primes.

Comment: For a counterexample, $q$ must be greater than $10\ 000$. Maybe, aurifeuillan factors could solve the problem, but unfortunately, I have no idea how. I came across the factors of $$\frac{521^{521}-1}{520}$$ (a composite $706$ and a composite $707$ digit factor , see here : http://factordb.com/index.php?query=%28521%5E521-1%29%2F520) , so the question might be completely solveable. I asked a question, how the "monster factors" were found, but noone gave an enlightning answer yet.

Comment: @Peter I think you solved the problem. Reading the wikipedia page about aurifeuillian factors (I had no idea about these types of factors), it states that the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial evaluated at $n*x^2$ is reducible if and only if $n=1\pmod 4$ and is square-free, while the $2n$-th cyclotomic polynomial evaluated at $n*x^2$ is reducible if and only if $n=2,3\pmod 4$. For prime $n=1\pmod 4$ and $x=1$, this amounts to $n^n-1$ having an aurifeuillan factorization, while for prime $n=3\pmod 4$ and $x=1$ amounts to $n^n+1$ having an aurifeuillan factorization.

Comment: The next interesting thing is, given this information, is there a way to find the two composite factors of $(n^n+-1)/(n+-1)$ (given that $(n^n+-1)/(n+-1)$ has two special factors)? Based on what I already know, I don't know of an efficient way of finding the two composite factors of $(n^n+-1)/(n+-1)$ for prime $n$ (the form in the title is omitted and shortened).

Comment: Very good, this answer also this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854280/how-were-the-factors-of-frac521521-1520-found

Comment: You just have to factor the polynomial. This way, I actually could find the two non-trivial factors of $$\frac{521^{521}-1}{520}$$ mentioned in the linked question with PARI/GP.