# How were the factors of $\frac{521^{521}-1}{520}$ found?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

In factordb, I came across this factorization :

```
CF  1413 (show)     (521^521-1)/520<1413> = 8794442339...49<706> · 6489962533...29<707>
```

> How were these factors found ?

The factors should be algebraic or aurifeuillan factors, but I have no idea in which way. Any ideas ?

Comment: I think first we found two prime numbers, and then got the result by multiplying, and not vice versa.

Comment: It is notable that the two factors are about the same size. That probably made made it a lucky accident that it was even possible to find it. I'm not sure what method though.

Comment: @VladislavKharlamov You think someone just found a $706$-digit prime and a $707$-digit prime, and their product just happened to be $(521^{521}-1)/520$?

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a formula for the two factors (by the way both composite) and that they were not found by chance, or by ECM or by SIQS.

Comment: Click the section 6.3 link at [stdkmd.com/nrr/repunit/repunitnote.htm](http://stdkmd.com/nrr/repunit/repunitnote.htm) and there's some information about Aurifueillean factorization of repunits. This is beyond my experience but maybe others can derive something from it.

Comment: @Peter I did manage to find expressions $t$, in terms of $n$-th roots of unity such that the minimal polynomial of $t$ is an inverse factor of $\Phi_n(nx^2)$ or $\Phi_{2n}(nx^2)$. If there is a significant pattern between the expressions for prime $n$, then it could be used to compute the field norm of $t+1$... leading to a factor of $\Phi_n(nx^2)$ or $\Phi_{2n}(nx^2)$, and would answer how $(521^{521}-1)/520$ was factored. Please check it out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860577/minimal-polynomial-generators-of-aurifeuillan-factors-cyclotomic-polynomials

Comment: -1. You say "Any idea?", but you don't reply or upvote every comment or answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is a way to generate the reciprocal polynomial factors $\Phi_n(nx^2)$ or $\Phi_{2n}(nx^2)$ for prime $n$ depending on the congruence $\pmod 4$. The former are $1$ while the latter are $3$ $\pmod 4$. Given the field of $n$-th roots of unity, let $r$ be any primitive $n$-th root of unity, and $f$ is the first factor of $\Phi_n(nx^2)$ or $\Phi_{2n}(nx^2)$. Then there is a polynomial $t$ in terms of $r$ such that the minimal polynomial of $t$ is $f$. It is possible (but may require extensive computation), to generate this minimal polynomial for large prime $n$.

For example, take $n=5$, and

$\Phi_5(5x^2)=(25x^4 - 25x^3 + 15x^2 - 5x + 1)(25x^4 + 25x^3 + 15x^2 + 5x + 1)$

The reciprocal of the first factor is $x^4 - 5x^3 + 15x^2 - 25x + 25$.

If $r$ is a primitive $5$th root of unity, then the minimal polynomial of $r^3-r^2-r+1$ is $x^4 - 5x^3 + 15x^2 - 25x + 25$. When $r$ is a $10$th root of unity, the minimal polynomial $r^3-r^2-r+1$ is $x^4 - 5x^3 + 5x^2 + 5x + 5$. (I thought this would generate the second factor but I guess not). The computations were performed with PARI/GP:

```
(14:20) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(5)))
%76 = x^4 - 5*x^3 + 15*x^2 - 25*x + 25
(14:20) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(10)))
%77 = x^4 - 5*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 5*x + 5
(14:20) gp >
```

I also treated $r$ as an $n$-th root of unity for other prime $n$, taking the minimal polynomial of $r^3-r^2-r+1$ and obtained similar polynomials. I don't know weather these polynomials have any relation with the aurifeuillan factors of $\Phi_n(nx^2)$ or $\Phi_{2n}(nx^2)$ or could be used to solve factorization of $(n^n+-1)/(n+-1)$:

```
(14:22) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(5)))
%78 = x^4 - 5*x^3 + 15*x^2 - 25*x + 25
(14:22) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(7)))
%79 = x^6 - 7*x^5 + 21*x^4 - 35*x^3 + 49*x^2 - 49*x + 49
(14:22) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(11)))
%80 = x^10 - 11*x^9 + 55*x^8 - 165*x^7 + 341*x^6 - 506*x^5 + 484*x^4 - 242*x^3 + 121*x^2 + 121
(14:22) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(13)))
%81 = x^12 - 13*x^11 + 78*x^10 - 286*x^9 + 715*x^8 - 1300*x^7 + 1833*x^6 - 2028*x^5 + 1521*x^4 - 507*x^3 + 169*x^2 + 169*x + 169
(14:22) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(17)))
%82 = x^16 - 17*x^15 + 136*x^14 - 680*x^13 + 2380*x^12 - 6188*x^11 + 12393*x^10 - 19516*x^9 + 24310*x^8 - 24276*x^7 + 20808*x^6 - 16473*x^5 + 10404*x^4 - 2312*x^3 + 1156*x^2 + 1156*x + 289
(14:22) gp > minpoly(Mod(x^3-x^2-x+1,polcyclo(19)))
%83 = x^18 - 19*x^17 + 171*x^16 - 969*x^15 + 3876*x^14 - 11628*x^13 + 27132*x^12 - 50426*x^11 + 75905*x^10 - 93176*x^9 + 92416*x^8 - 73644*x^7 + 50901*x^6 - 35739*x^5 + 23104*x^4 - 4332*x^3 + 3249*x^2 + 2166*x + 361
```

Any leads further from this?

Answer (score 2):

That formula, $$\frac{n^n - 1}{n - 1},$$ looks so familiar. Maybe it has something to do with my question (with a soon-to-expire bounty) about reciprocating pseudoprimes.

You asked for "any ideas." The first idea I often tell people is to look it up in the OEIS. But first I ran the query `(n^n - 1)/(n - 1)` on factordb, with slight trepidation that the server could blow up at having to divide by 0 (for $n = 1$).

From that factordb query, I got enough numbers to do an OEIS search and get just one result: http://oeis.org/A023037

> For $n \geq 1$, $a(n)$ is the number whose base $n$ representation is a string of $n$ ones. For example, 11111 in base 5 is $a(5) = 781$. - Melvin Peralta, May 23 2016

Of course! $a(n)$ is a base $n$ repunit. And repunits are almost always composite. If $b$ is the base of numeration and $n = b$, then $$\frac{b^n - 1}{n - 1} = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} b^i,$$ and... oops, sorry, that was not as fruitful as I had hoped.

Okay, so we know that this base $n$ repunit is divisible by any factors of $n^n - 1$ that are coprime to $n - 1$. Then, for 521, we see that $520 = 2^3 \times 5 \times 13$.

And then we can confirm that $521^{521} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, $521^{521} \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and $521^{521} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$... sorry, another dead end.

So when is this base $n$ repunit prime? Clearly $n$ itself must be prime. I increased my factordb query to $n = 200$ and got 2, 3, 19, 31, which I feared would give me too many results in the OEIS. It just got me four, and the first one was http://oeis.org/A088790

The next prime is 7547. Still, this does nothing to diminish my astonishment at the discovery of the two factors for the base 521 repunit. There must be something algebraic going on. Maybe something of what I've said helps you, or maybe I've just given you a bunch of red herrings.

Comment: I would rather guess aurifeuillan factors, I thought of something like $$4a^4+b^4=(2a^2-2ab+b^2)(2a^2+2ab+b^2)$$ but I did not find suitable numbers $a,b$

Comment: If $n=1\pmod 4$ is prime, then the first factor of $\Phi_n(nx^2)$ has leading coefficient $n^{(n-1)/2}$, the same idea with $n=3\pmod 4$ prime and $\Phi_{2n}(nx^2)$. All coefficients of the first factor are multiples of $n$. The second factor is the the negative valuation of the first factor (i.e. if the first factor is $f(x)$, then the second one is $f(-x)$.

Comment: I also suspect there is a way to possibly generate the inverse of the first factor (which is monic) by taking the minimal polynomial of some expression containing an $n$-th root of unity.